# How can I see and select the Vertex of the Mesh in Weight Painting Mode in Blender 2.8?

Tags: weight-painting

I dislike the brush for the weight painting, I want to be able to select vertex and add the amount of weight I want manually. That's something I can do on blender 2.7 but not in blender 2.8, I can't even see the wireframe of the model in blender 2.8 while doing the weight painting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're referring to in 2.7 but in 2.8 you can display the wire with the *Viewport Overlay* > *Wire* option, and if you switch to *Edit* mode you can select a vertex then in the *N* panel > *Item* > *Vertex Weights*, set the weight you want.

[image]